# Remove folder if it has another folder with the same started numbers

Tags: command-line, directory, rm

I have some folders that have been created in error. I would like remove these folders.

```
¬ 636
¬ 636.empty
¬ 637
¬ 638.empty
¬ 639
¬ 639.empty
```

In this situation I would like to remove `636.empty` and leave the remaining none empty folder.

After I have ran the terminal command I would like all folders that a `sister` folder to be removed.

```
¬ 636
¬ 637
¬ 638.empty
¬ 639
```

Removed folders would be:

```
¬ 636.empty
¬ 639.empty
```

I have some `25,000` folders maybe `1000`  of these are duplicates with the `empty` folder

Comment: I guess that the folders you want to delete don't end always in `.empty`. Is that correct?

Comment: I have updated the question. I am also sorry that I do not have any working examples of code that I have tried to write myself.

Comment: @Jamie Hutber To make sure we know what you want, 1) do you want to delete all directories which end in `.empty`? Yes/No? 2) Are all the directories you wish to remove under the same directory? Yes/No? Please click [edit] and provide more clarification. Please do not use Add Comment, but instead just use [edit].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loop through all directories named `*empty` and check if same directory without `.empty` exists and delete if true:

```bsh
for d in *.empty; do
    [ -d "$d" ] && [ -d "${d%.empty}" ] && rmdir "$d"
done
```

Replace `rmdir` with `rm -rf` if the directory is not empty despite its name ;-)

---

A `find` alternative:

```bsh
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*.empty' \
  -exec sh -c '[ -d "${1%.empty}" ]' find-sh {} \; \
  -delete
```

Replace `-delete` with `-exec rm -rf {} \;` if the directory is not empty.